# Asp.net mvc application throwing js syntax errors before users are logged in

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When inspecting the browser console, why is it that my application throws some javascript errors at me at the login page?

I've set my web.config to contain the following:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="90" />
</authentication>
```

And then I have a `_AnonymousUserLayout.cshtml` that contains the following scripts:

```
<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")"></script>

<!-- Supersized JS -->
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/supersized.core.3.2.1.js")"></script>
```

And in my `Login.cshtml` (Rendered through RenderBody() in the layout-file) I'm including the following:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In my `Global.asax.cs` I have defined this filter:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

Lastly, I'm redirected to the login page in my `_ViewStart.cshtml`:

```
@{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";    
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AnonymousUserLayout.cshtml";
    }

}
```

Whenever I'm not logged in and redirected to the login page, I keep seeing the following errors in the developer console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :54837/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FScripts%2Fkendo%2F2013.1.319%2Fjquery.min.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :54837/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FScripts%2Fkendo%2F2013.1.319%2Fkendo.all.min.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < Login?ReturnUrl=%2FScripts%2Fkendo%2F2013.1.319%2Fkendo.aspnetmvc.min.js:1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my ASP.Net experience (not MVC):  If Forms Authentication is enabled, you have to bypass the authentication for all the scripts and images that are being used in the login page.  This is done by using the web.config's location element as per the below sample:

```
<location path="<your path>jquery-1.8.2.js">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same problem after some R & D I have found that I need to give below code in web config:

```
<location path="Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```